# FTP C# console 2010 sending data.dat file of 71kb i get a file in my ftp but it is 0byte

Tags: c#, file, upload, ftp

okay so basically I am using the class object from here

```
http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/443588/Simple-Csharp-FTP-Class
```

I have then created my main program file here it is

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        /* Create Object Instance */
        ftp ftpClient = new ftp(@"ftp://ftp.drivehq.com/", "ashg1990", "Robert12");

        /* Upload a File */
        ftpClient.upload("stat.dat", @"C:\Users\ash\AppData\Roaming\EruptMiner\Stats.dat");
    }
}
}
```

this code works to a degree but the file I get is a 0byte one so it not the original and is blank can any one help me

Comment: First thing I've noticed - you seem to be misunderstanding what setting a variable to `null` does...

Comment: can u help me fix this

Comment: @JonSkeet your help on this would be appreciated it the first time I have used this source